# Is there a version of ?rep that receives "each" as a vector? (R question)

Tags: r, repeat

(please ignore this question - it is foolish...)

I want something that will do this:

```
rep(1:3, each = 1:3)
# And will output this vector:
c(1,2,2,3,3,3)
```

Does it exist? (and if so, how?)

Update: I can write it like this -

```
rep2 <- function(x, each)
{
    output <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(x))
    {
        output <- c(output, rep(x[i], each = each[i]))
    }
    return(output)
}
# example:
rep2(1:3,1:3)
```

But am hoping for a smarter solution...

Comment: It's okay Tal, we all have our moments... ;-)

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I appreciate the kindness :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rep(1:3,1:3)
```

Surely that works as your example. For info, the argument for the `rep` function is `times`, `each` is a single integer (or the first element of a vector) which determines the repetition of all elements of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm this:

```
> rep(1:3, 1:3)
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

You want the 'times=' argument, not 'each='.